# Monitor Network Performance of VPN Servers from different locations

Tags: vpn, performance, monitoring

Our company has 3 VPN Servers in US. We want to monitor network performance ( the most important factor is how fast users from different locations in the world can download data when using our servers ). Is there any service or application for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a script that tests this and deploy it on multiple locations world-wide (rent out a small VPS or spin up EC2-instances when needed).

Make sure the script has one of three outcomes:

- OK
- WARNING
- CRITICAL

You can add some additional info after that.

You could then install Icinga (Nagios fork) and use check_nrpe to run the test-script you wrote from the icinga-server on specific intervals and report back to Icinga. This would give you a nice overview of how all off the servers are doing from different locations in one dashboard.

More info:

- [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/)
- [check_nrpe](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/doc/usage/nagios/nrpe)
- [NConf](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php) (Makes configuration easier)

[image: Icinga screenshot]

This works for both Windows & Linux.

Comment: It seems interesting. But Do u have any suggestion on the script? How can I test speed of vpn connections?

Comment: Write a script that connects to the VPN and downloads a test file. Then parse the output you get from `wget`.

Comment: Yes. I can also ping connected users from VPN Servers and parse the result. This way, I don't need to rent VPS in different locations. I use users to test the speed! Does it work?

Comment: True. You could then use the RTT/RTD to calculate the quality. Then you could run the script one each VPN server for a few random clients (pick a few from the dhcp-lease). It would however be harder to get clear results because you got to take into account that people are not always in ideal situation and the results might be flawed.

Comment: Do you know how much RAM do I need to run icinga for monitoring 3 servers?

Comment: I currently check on ~200 services with 256 MB RAM.

Comment: In Icinga recommendations they say it requires 2GB of RAM for 100 devices. I was scared! Thank you.